# Generating Code Based on a Table in Julia

Tags: sequence, code-generation, julia

I have a sequence of code:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:minSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-1-2010
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:maxSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-2-2010
```

I need to change

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:minSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-1-2010
```

and

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:maxSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-2-2010
```

to be the next two day period:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:minSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-3-2010

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:maxSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-4-2010
```

so that the resulting full set of code has entries for every two day period from 1-1-2010 to 12-31-2013.

I have generated a DataFrame that has every one of these dates (code posted below). I don't know if referencing this table will be the easiest way to alter the dates, but it was one method I was thinking of. I also do not know if Julia can solve my question, but it is one of the languages I feel more comfortable with.

```
a=collect(Date("2010-01-01"):Dates.Day(1):Date("2013-12-31"))
dates=DataFrame(Dates=a)
```

An excerpt of what the final code should look like is shown below.

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:minSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-1-2010
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:maxSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-2-2010

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:minSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-3-2010
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:maxSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-4-2010

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:minSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-5-2010
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:dc ATTR=ID:maxSEARCH_CLOSED_DATE CONTENT=1-6-2010
```

Comment: There's a lot of unnecessary stuff here. Can the problem description be simplified?

Comment: I will delete the unnecessary stuff. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas There we go.

Comment: Given your definition of your dates `a`, you are almost there. You can extract the day with `Dates.day(d)` etc., where `d` iterates over `a`. Then you just need to construct the string correctly, with `string("some stuff ", Dates.day(d), "-", ...)` etc.

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders The code shown is only a portion of the script. The rest of the code contains sections with quotation marks. As a second " marks the end of the string, do you know a workaround for this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use triple-quoted (multiline) strings: `s = """He said "Hello" """`

Comment: @DavidP.Sanders I'll try that later today. Thanks!